# Looping through rows in 2d list

Tags: python, list, 2d, puzzle

In an earlier post I talked about creating a binary puzzle. I'm applying a check mechanism. So far my check mechanism is working, but only on the columns.

This my board:

```
board = []
for i in range (1, col+1):
    bord.append([' ']*col
```

`col` is a variable, so the board can be of any size.

It looks something like this:

```
   A   B   C   D   E
1  ''  '' ''   '' ''
2  ''  '' ''   '' ''
3  ''  '' ''   '' ''
4  ''  '' ''   '' ''
```

and it's filled (or will be filled) with `0`, `1`.

Here is my check mechanism:

```
def chekbaord(board):
  ok = True
 for i in range (0, len(board[0])):
   s = ""
   for j in range(0, len(board)):
         s = s +board[i][j]
   if "111" in s or "000" in s:
     print("not possible")
```

This check works fine just on columns (x-axis). I'm having trouble looping through the list in the y-axis (rows). I don't know how to loop through the list that way.

Comment: Where is your attempt, and what precisely is the problem with it? Referring to *"an earlier post"* is not helpful; if there is relevant information, provide it **in this question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap `range` in `for` loops as:

```
def chekbaord(board):
  ok = True
 for i in range (0, len(board)):   # board[0] changed to board
   s = ""
   for j in range(0, len(board[0])):   # board changed to board[0]
         s = s +board[i][j]
   if "111" in s or "000" in s:
     print("not possible")
```

Comment: You also need to swap `i` and `j` in `board[i][j]` - in case the board isn't square. Actually, I would just swap `i` and `j` in the `for` statements and leave `board[i][j]` alone.